# CSS order of applying bug

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
   <div id="inner"></div>
   <div id="..."></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer div {
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#inner {
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```

My problem is with the inner div style. It seems that margin: 0 auto is always more important than margin-top. It is the same when I put `#outer div {...}` below `#inner {...}`

I would like to know how to fix this without using important. Any idea?

Comment: `#inner{margin: 10px auto 0 auto}` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug. `#outer div` is a more [specific selector](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) than `#inner`. You can think of CSS specificity as a points based system. In this case each of your two rules gets 10 points for referencing an ID. The first rule (which includes the div element) gets an extra 1 point. That makes `#outer div` have 11 points and `#inner` is left with just 10. This means `#outer div` the rule that is applied to the element.

```
#outer #inner {
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```

The above rule would have *20* points and be applied to the element.

Comment: This is a great answer and it helped me solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be like this:

```
#outer div:nth-child(1)  /*instead of #inner */
{
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#outer div:nth-child(n+2)
{
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```